# Android 3.0+ ActionBar doesn't show

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

My app is compatible from Android 2.x through 4.x:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"
/>
```

For my application theme, I'm using a selector theme as suggested on the [Android dev website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/LightThemeSelector"
>
```

I have several /res/values-* directories to control styles on different sizes/versions of Android devices. For example, in /res/values-large.xml I have the selector choose the old android Light theme:

```
<style
    name="LightThemeSelector"
    parent="android:Theme.Light"
>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

However, in my /res/values-sw720dp.xml (and /res/values-sw600dp.xml) I have the selector choose the new android Holo.Light theme which should automatically provide me with an ActionBar:

```
<style
    name="LightThemeSelector"
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"
>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

However, when I run the app on a XOOM simulator it doesn't show an ActionBar. If I set the Manifest file to directly specify the Theme.Holo.Light then I do get the ActionBar when I run in my XOOM emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is this line:

`<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

When you set it to true, it hides the ActionBar.

Just set it to `false` and you should be set.